# XSLT Returning Distinct Sets of Data from multiple Element Level

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am currently stuck at getting a distinct set of values with value of `<NAME>` being the key.
I have the following sample XML:

```
<SAMPLE>
    <FIRST>
        <SUBSET>
            <DATA>
                <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
            </DATA>
            <FILE>
                <NAME>DataName5</NAME>
            </FILE>         
        </SUBSET>
    </FIRST>
    <SECOND>
        <DATA>
            <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
        </DATA> 
        <FILE>
            <NAME>DataName2</NAME>
        </FILE> 
        <DATA>
            <NAME>DataName3</NAME>
        </DATA>         
    </SECOND>
    <THIRD>
        <DATA>
            <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
        </DATA>
        <FILE>
            <NAME>DataName4</NAME>
        </FILE>         
    </THIRD>
</SAMPLE>
```

what I am trying to achieve, is to get the NAME values from both DATA and File Tags which the is following as results:

```
<SAMPLE>
   <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
   <NAME>DataName2</NAME>
   <NAME>DataName3</NAME>
   <NAME>DataName4</NAME>
   <NAME>DataName5</NAME>
</SAMPLE>
```

Below is my code using `[(NAME=preceding::NAME)]` but it is not working..

```
<xsl:template name="Sample">
    <SAMPLE>    
        <xsl:for-each select="((($srcFile/SAMPLE/FIRST/SUBSET)|($srcFile/SAMPLE/SECOND)|($srcFile/SAMPLE/THIRD))/(DATA | FILE))[(NAME=preceding::NAME)]">
                <xsl:for-each select="NAME"><xsl:element name="{name(.)}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element></xsl:for-each>                    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </SAMPLE>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="Sample"/>                 
</xsl:template>
```

the above code in the for-each section, unfortunately, only returned the following:

```
<SAMPLE>
   <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
   <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
</SAMPLE>
```

taking out `[(NAME=preceding::NAME)]`, unfortunately, would return all duplicated results.. I thought I have the filter code in the right place because I've even added the overall () before using this filter[]

Thanks in advance for all of the help/suggestions!

Comment: R.C. See short and efficient ( O(N) )  XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 solutions in my answer. Your attempted grouping by using the `preceding::` axis is incomplete and also quite inefficient -- O(N^2) and is not recommended.

Comment: @R.C I have rolled back your question to its original form. Please post your new question separately, instead of modifying this one so substantially after it has been already answered.

Comment: @R.C I restored back the last version of your question, as it already has an answer. In the future, please, ask a new question and do not edit the original question too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. Just use** (XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('file:///C:/temp/delete/sample.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$vDoc/*/SECOND/SET" group-by="NAME">
      <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any source XML document** (not used), and the file `C:\temp\delete\sample.xml` (Note I have changed the value of `SAMPLE\FIRST\SET\NAME` to show that it is not copied to the result tree) **is**:

```
<SAMPLE>
    <FIRST>
        <SET>
            <NAME>manX</NAME>
            <STRING1>what</STRING1>
            <STRING2>today</STRING2>
        </SET>
    </FIRST>
    <SECOND>
        <SET>
            <NAME>man1</NAME>
            <STRING1>what</STRING1>
            <STRING2>today</STRING2>
        </SET>
        <SET>
            <NAME>man1</NAME>
            <STRING1>what</STRING1>
            <STRING2>today</STRING2>
        </SET>
        <SET>
            <NAME>man2</NAME>
            <STRING1>how</STRING1>
            <STRING2>tomorrow</STRING2>
        </SET>
        <SET>
            <NAME>man3</NAME>
            <STRING1>hello</STRING1>
            <STRING2>yesterday</STRING2>
        </SET>
    </SECOND>
</SAMPLE>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<SET>
   <NAME>man1</NAME>
   <STRING1>what</STRING1>
   <STRING2>today</STRING2>
</SET>
<SET>
   <NAME>man2</NAME>
   <STRING1>how</STRING1>
   <STRING2>tomorrow</STRING2>
</SET>
<SET>
   <NAME>man3</NAME>
   <STRING1>hello</STRING1>
   <STRING2>yesterday</STRING2>
</SET>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('file:///C:/temp/delete/sample.xml')"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSecondSetsByName" match="SECOND/SET" use="NAME"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc/*/SECOND"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SET[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kSecondSetsByName', NAME)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Explanation**:

1. Use of the standard XSLT 2.0 instruction `<xsl:for-each-group>` with the attribute `group-by`.
2. Use of the **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** in the XSLT 1.0 solution

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, this is rather trivial:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <SAMPLE>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//NAME)">
            <NAME>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </NAME>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </SAMPLE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestions, is there a way to use this method if the XML file is external(uses $srcFile as reference like `<xsl:variable name="srcFile" select="document('file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Sample.xml')"/>`), and also there are other data other than name in a set so within for-each of the source, I would have 2 other for-each to loop thru the dataset(Name and Type). thanks for your suggestions

Comment: The answer to the first part is yes: just point the function to the correct path e.g, `distinct-values($srcFile//NAME)`. I did not understand the second part.

Comment: to explain this better, I will probably delete this post and resubmit some code that is more accurate.. sorry for the inconvenience. Please take a look at the new post if possible later. thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael, since I can't delete the post, I have modified the question, if you don't mind, please re-read it when you have a chance? thanks so much for helping out!

Comment: @R.C There is no need to delete this question. However, you should  ask a new question, instead of changing this one to something completely different - after your original question has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

A simple XSLT-1.0 solution is excluding duplicates and sorting them by their lexical order. Generating an `xsl:key` of all `NAME` nodes and comparing this list again to all `NAME` nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:key name="names" match="NAME" use="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/SAMPLE">
    <SAMPLE>
      <xsl:for-each select="//NAME[generate-id() = generate-id(key('names',text()))]">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />
        <NAME><xsl:value-of select="." /></NAME>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </SAMPLE>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SAMPLE>
    <NAME>DataName1</NAME>
    <NAME>DataName2</NAME>
    <NAME>DataName3</NAME>
    <NAME>DataName4</NAME>
    <NAME>DataName5</NAME>
</SAMPLE>
```